# Frustrated trying to migrate from v1 to Recaptcha v2 in Java application using Struts2 framework

Tags: java, recaptcha

I have an existing Java application on Struts 2 framework.  While trying to migrate away from captcha v1 and implement v2, I am not having any luck.  I'm hoping someone can help, I would think this should be basic.  The I'm not a robot just sits and spins when it is clicked and nothing goes to my action class until I click submit. I have tried replacing the sitekey in jsp with my actual key hard-coded.  No luck.  Here are my new code snippets:

my.jsp

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=<s:property value="#session.captchaPublicKey"/>"></div>
```

In my action action class on submit:

```
public void validateCaptcha() throws Exception{
  logger.debug("in captcha validate");  
  String gRecaptchaResponse = request.getParameter("g-recaptcha-response");
    System.out.println(gRecaptchaResponse);
    boolean verify = Captcha.verify(gRecaptchaResponse);
    System.out.println("Captcha Verify"+verify);
    //RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
    if (!verify == true) {
        addActionError("You missed the Captcha.");      

    }

}
```

My Captcha.java class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonReader;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class Captcha {

public static final String url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
public static final String secret = WamProps.getProperty("RECAPTCHA_PRIVATEKEY");
private final static String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

public static boolean verify(String gRecaptchaResponse) throws IOException {
    if (gRecaptchaResponse == null || "".equals(gRecaptchaResponse)) {
        return false;
    }

    try{
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    String postParams = "secret=" + secret + "&response="+ gRecaptchaResponse;

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(postParams);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    // print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

    //parse JSON response and return 'success' value
    JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(response.toString()));
    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonReader.readObject();
    jsonReader.close();

    return jsonObject.getBoolean("success");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use Struts.  https://thehackernews.com/2017/09/apache-struts-vulnerability.html

Comment: I don't have a choice right now.  It is an existing application that is very large and I don't have the time to do a rewrite.

Comment: And we do not use the REST plugin.

Comment: I knew you'd say that.  You should know what a security risk you're taking on and plan to change it as soon as possible.  Tell your clients that you're using an insecure framework so they can plan accordingly to lose their data.